# getters setters array

Tags: c#, arrays, element, setter, getter

Probably a really simple problem i can't fix - I'm starting out with C# and need to add values to an array with a getter/setter method for example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] array = new string[] { "just","putting","something","inside","the","array"};


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Array = "gdgd";
    }

    public string[] Array
    {
        get { return array; }
        set { array = value; }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Tell me the problem :D

Comment: You can't *add* values to an array anyway...

Comment: Well this will not work : Array = "gdgd"; you cant set an String to an Array

Comment: it would work if he hadn't specified the stuff inside the array, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Malachi: No, you can never assign a `string` to a `string[]` property.

Comment: right, I meant he could use an array in this fashion if he sends a string to an array location (Array[3]), in an array that hasn't had the size defined, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is never going to work:

```
Array = "gdgd";
```

That's trying to assign a `string` value to a `string[]` property. Note that you can't add or remove elements in an array anyway, as once they've been created the size is fixed. Perhaps you should use a `List<string>` instead:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<string> list = new List<string> { 
        "just", "putting", "something", "inside", "the", "list"
    };    

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List.Add("gdgd");
    }

    public List<string> List
    {
        get { return list; }
        set { list = value; }
    }
}
```

Note that having the public property is irrelevant here anyway, as you're accessing it from within the same class - you can just use the field:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list.Add("gdgd");
}
```

Also note that for "trivial" properties like this you can use an automatically implemented property:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<string> List { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List = new List<string> { 
            "just", "putting", "something", "inside", "the", "list"
        };    
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List.Add("gdgd");
    }
}
```

Comment: Else you have to make a big array string[] array = new string[1000] and add values with setting up different indexes. But the solution with List<string> is 10times smarter ;)

Comment: alright, thanks for the answers. i will use a list where you dont have an ending like in the array, in order to add values without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

inside your set method you need to add code so that it can add to a specific array location, unless you are sending it an array, if that is the case then what you have should work.

if you send it a string, like you are you need to specify the array location.

```
Array[index] = "gdgd"
```

otherwise it looks like you are assigning to a string variable and not an Array

Answer (score 0):

Use a List to hold the values. When you need to return the array, use    List.ToArray()